# sharepoint O365 excel web Access is Blank!

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-web-access-webpart

I went through lists of similar answered questions but non seemed to have the answer.

[image]

We are currently in O365 SharePoint and this is Excel Web Access.

For me and some other employees, this is actually working fine.

However, for some of the employees, this is what they see...

What could be the possible fix for this?

Someone mentioned to post change .xlsx to .xls but this did not work.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the points below to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Navigate to the library which the excel file come from, check if the user has permission to the file.
2. Edit the Excel Web Access web part, check if it is set Target Audiences in Advanced section.
3. Switch to another browser or clear the browser cache to check again.